# Generating tileable 2D texture from non-tileable 3D texture

Tags: graphics, textures, procedural-generation

I am working on a library for procedural texture generation (https://github.com/mikera/clisk) which is starting to come together quite nicely.

I'm now trying to work out good ways of producing **tileable 2D textures**.

One approach that seems plausible is to map the (0,0) - (1,1) 2D texture space onto a surface within a 3D texture in such a way that the surface connects the left and right edges and top and bottom edges of the texture (e.g. a torus). In doing so, that should ensure that the 2D texture is automatically tileable.

Since I already have good (non-tileable) 3D textures (perlin noise, fractal noise etc.) this seems like it would be a good way to allow the creation of tileable 2D textures from an arbitrary 3D texture.

So my quesyions:

- Is this a valid technique?
- If so, what kind of surface should I map onto in order to minimise distortions / get an good looking tiling effect?
- Any pitfalls to be aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using 3D noise for this will produce distortion, the answer is to use 4D noise, though that is not the only way - you can also make the 2D function tileable.

Here's a couple of useful links:

- http://www.gamedev.net/blog/33/entry-2138456-seamless-noise/

  - Introduces the 4D method
- https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/23625/how-do-you-generate-tileable-perlin-noise

  - Has multiple answers for this: making the 2D tileable, 3D with distortion, and the 4D method